# How to make out schema (or extract) out of imported json data using mongoimport.?

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I have a task, where I need to import (mongo DB) data from a json (or I may have to insert) which has array of docs. Now after importing data I have to perform CRUD ops. Say, I have imported, how to extract or construct **schema** for the imported data which is actually a kind of reverse engineering. Or if I have already defined a schema based on data that I am going to import, how to validate with respect to type of data, at respective fields.? Hope I am able to make reader understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can import easy array of json documents with the mongoimport command as follow:

   mongoimport --db test --collection example --type json --file example.json --jsonArray

the file need to look as follow:

```
[ {} , {} , {} ]
```

2. You may get random samples from the collection to see how the document looks like and based on the document to construct the schema:

   db.example.aggregate( [ { $sample: { size: 3 } } ] )

( Indeed you need to do some reverse engenering to understand how data to be used )

3. Latest versions of mongodb >=3.2 provide the option to create json schema validation , check here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/

I hope my answer give you some directions ... ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got an idea to push further. Or may be, got what I have to ... Will go through the link.